# how to convert mongoose bson type to mongoose objectID

Tags: angularjs, mongoose, mongoose-schema

```
 var doc = new mongoose.Document(data, schema);



currencyCode: "USD"
date: "2019-12-17T14:14:00.000"
lineItems:[]
locationId: "5c2e27557bbe1300b7a3cd8c"
loyaltyID: "testtest1"
srcChannelID: "Corporate"
srcChannelType: "Web"
tenderItems: []
type: "Accrual"
value: 0
_id: {bsontype:ObjectID}
```

id is creating like this instead of objectid. Can you please help me out.

Comment: Did You find a solution?